# how to use state server for session in asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, session

I need to know the procedure to use asp.net session state server for session.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

1. Start the stat session windows service
2. Add the following entry to your web.config file:

   <sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"  cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="10" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
3. Configure the values in the above entry according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx)

Note that if you used to use the inProc sessions before, you will not be able to store non serializable objects in session anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very good [article on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ExploringSession.aspx) which will step-by-step guide you how to do this..

**http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ExploringSession.aspx**